# Change URL without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm developing a blog site, and i'm having some problems with the pagination.

Before sharing my code;

- All the code on the site has been written by me, trying to NOT use a ext library.
- I only use JQuery
- Ergo, i'm open to ANY suggestion.

Now, the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pageItem = $('.pagination li').not('.prev,.next');
  var prev = $('.pagination li.prev');
  var next = $('.pagination li.next');

  prev.addClass('disabled');
  pageItem.first().addClass('active');

  pageItem.click(function () {
    pageItem.removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.prev,.next').addClass('active');

    if ($(this).next().hasClass('next')) {
      next.addClass('disabled');
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    }

    if ($(this).prev().hasClass('prev')) {
      prev.addClass('disabled');
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  next.click(function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

    if (next.prev().hasClass('active')) {
      next.addClass('disabled');
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  prev.click(function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');

    if (prev.next().hasClass('active')) {
      prev.addClass('disabled');
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.pagination li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #7c3c01;
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.disabled a span {
  color: #000000;
}
.active {
  background-color: #e99d57;
  color: #633001;
}
.pagination li:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f0b680;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="prev">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Anterior">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!--
            Here's my php code to load the articles from db
            
            <?php
            // PAGINACION
            $total_art = mysqli_num_rows($entradas);
            $art_x_page = 4;
            $pages = ceil($total_art / $art_x_page);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?pagina=<?= $i + 1; ?>"><?= $i + 1; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            
            To make the example work, i will add some static li
            -->

                <li>
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                
            <li class="next">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Siguiente">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

If u test my pagination, you will see that it work nice.
My problem is the php part, when i add it the page reload to bring the data and refresh the page.So the styles/script aren't working anymore. Anytime the page reload the style is the same (the .prev is .disabled and the first li is .active).

What i need is to load data from db without reload the page (so my styles/scripts still work) OR a way to modify my script after the reload.
I've been reading a little about AJAX, i think that's what i need but i can't implement it to my code, i think i don't understand it very well.

Thank you!

Comment: Ajax is what you want if you want new content inserted without a full page reload

Comment: Can u recomend me a video or document where i can learn about it? I have read some tutos but i dont get it yet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is `ajaxs` to solve your problem
so lets say your current code is in content.php

**content.php**

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="prev">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Anterior">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>

                <li class="page_num">
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page_num">
                    <a  href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page_num">
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>

            <li class="next">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Siguiente">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div id="result">
<!-- Load Data here -->
</div>
<script>
 $( ".page_num").click(function(e) { 

    let page_num = $(this).text().trim();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/load_data.php', //location to your php file
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          page_num: page_num //data to send to the load_data.php file
      },

      success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
      }

    });

 }); 
</script>
```

**load_data.php**

```
<?php 
$page_num = $_POST["page_num"];
//your php logic here 
echo "MY Content";

?>
```

so basically anything you echo in the **load_data.php** file it will get output in the **content.php** file in the div `id="result"`
now this will load your content without having the page reload

Comment: i posted the answer but if u dont get it u can join chat so i can probably explain a bit better
https://hack.chat/?stackoverflow_help

Comment: i'm trying to get it, thank you! i will join the chat if i can't understand it

Comment: @Juanenriquez let me know how it goes

Comment: After a 2 hours vid about Ajax, i finally get ir. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Juanenriquez i am glad you got it :)